# Splitting legend in ggtree/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I am using a piece of software called `ggtree`, which is based on `ggplot2` and allows you to visualise a phylogenetic tree and add metadata to it. The function for adding the metadata as a coloured heatmap is called `gheatmap` and as I understand it simply correlates rownames in a data.frame or matrix with the labels of the tree. The rest of the language associated with it is basically `ggplot2`.

The data is here: https://github.com/CJREID/gheatmap

With the following code I have generated the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17492.png).

```
library(ggtree)

#read in tree
tree <- read.tree("example_tree_overflow.tree")
p <- ggtree(tree)

#add tip labels and scale
p <- p + geom_tiplab(size = 2.4, align = TRUE, linesize = .2) +
                      geom_treescale()

#group and colour clades

p <- p %>% groupClade(node=c(72,75,84)) + aes(color=group) +
  scale_color_discrete() + 
  theme(legend.position = NULL)

#import data.frame and add column names

meta <- read.csv("metadata_overflow.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
rownames(meta) <- meta[,1]
meta <- meta[,2:7]
colnames(meta) <- c("Origin", "Syndrome", "fimH", "CTX-M","gyrA","parC")

#variable to generate the breaks in the legend

q1 <- c("REF","SAN","OBH","CoH",
      "Cystitis","Pyelonephritis","Sepsis",
      "H22","H30","H41",
      "CTX-M-1_15","CTX-M-9_18","CTX-M-9_27",
      "WT","S83L", "S83L_D87N",
      "WT","S80I_E84V")

#colour values for the legend, sorry they're awful, I will fix them later

c1 <- c("black","blue","green","red",
        "yellow","purple","firebrick",
        "turquoise","purple","olivedrab",
        "red","purple","turquoise",
        "white","purple","turquoise",
        "white", "turquoise")

#assign breaks to colours
names(c1) <- q1

#draw heatmap next to tree, assigning colours correctly to the variables 

gheatmap(p, meta, colnames_position = "top", width = .06, offset = .025, 
          font.size = 2, colnames_angle = 50, colnames_offset_y = .2, 
          colnames_offset_x = -0.0019, hjust = 0) + 
          theme(legend.title = element_text()) +
           scale_fill_manual(name="Origin",
                            breaks=q1, 
                            values=c1)
```

As you can see, the data I have added is split into 6 categories `"Origin", "Syndrome", "fimH", "CTX-M", "gyrA", "parC"` Each with their own variables, as follows,

```
>plots
$Origin
[1] "REF" "SAN" "OBH" "CoH"

$Syndrome
[1] "Cystitis" "Pyelonephritis" "Sepsis"        

$fimH
[1] "H22" "H30" "H41"

$`CTX-M`
[1] "CTX-M-1_15" "CTX-M-9_18" "CTX-M-9_27"

$gyrA
[1] "WT"        "S83L"      "S83L_D87N"

$parC
[1] "WT"        "S80I_E84V".
```

I have two major issues:

1. I want to split these variables under their respective titles on the legend so they are six discrete legends. As you can see I have only managed to put one title "Origin" above the whole lot of them. (I have tried using this above `plots` object instead of `q1` as the `breaks` in `scale_fill_manual` to no avail)
2. I want the variable `WT` under `gyrA` and `WT` under `parC` to be treated separately i.e have their own boxes in the legend under their respective categorical titles.

Hopefully the solution is not as complicated as I think it might be

Cheers.

Comment: Please make a simple reproducible example to illustrate your problem, and for us to test solutions.

Comment: One possible way is to make six plots with the legends you want, use `cowplot::get_legend` to retreive them, then use `cowplot` to build a plot with all six legends included.

Comment: I've added the data in github so it can reproduced. Cheers